# python random customerID

Tags: python, pandas, random

everyone,
I have an OrderID as shown below in the first column. In the second column, I need to assign Customer ID on random basis based on the following criteria:

Given same OrderID, the CustomerID should be same;
CustomerID can repeat more than 1 times but be limited by 5 times since customer can buy more than once.  For example, customer 123 has two OrderID: A01 and A03.

```
OrderID CustomerID
A01 123
A01 123
A02 145
A03 123
A02 145
```

the following is my try but did not meet my purpose.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df['CustomerID'] = np.random.randint(100, 999, len(df))
```

Comment: Is the customer ID supposed to be generated from the OrderID?

Comment: "assign Customer ID on random basis" is not compatible with this: "Given same OrderID, the CustomerID should be same" — is it random or isn't it?

Comment: Why did it not meet your purpose?

Comment: If np.random.randint not in (Customer ID), is it valid? or CustomerID has each number between 100 and 999?

Answer (score 0):

From your syntax, I'm assuming you're using `pandas` (I added a `pandas` tag to your original post). You may find a better way to do this, but here is one way, by creating a separate dataframe called `customers` that contains only your unique Order IDs and a random int for each, then merging it together with your original dataframe:

If you're starting with a dataframe with only `OrderID`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Original df:
>>> df
  OrderID
0     A01
1     A01
2     A02
3     A03
4     A02

customers = pd.DataFrame({'OrderID':df['OrderID'].unique(), 
                     'CustomerID':np.random.randint(100,999, len(df['OrderID'].unique()))})

df = df.merge(customers, on='OrderID')

# New df:
>>> df
  OrderID  CustomerID
0     A01         513
1     A01         513
2     A02         279
3     A02         279
4     A03         655
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please upvote and/or accept answers to show your appreciation :)!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
    import uuid
order_ids_map = {} # mapping order ids to customer ids
order_ids = ['A01', 'A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A02']

for order_id in order_ids:
    if order_id not in order_ids_map:   # create new customer id
        customer_id = uuid.uuid4()
        order_ids_map[order_id] = customer_id
    print str.format('customer id for order id {0} is {1}', order_id, str(customer_id))
# now order_ids_map contains a map between order_ids and customer_ids
```